# Switching x or y values using a sign (-ve) transformation in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I have a data set which I am plotting using Plotly in Python. Take for example data_set_1_x = [1, 2, 3] and data_set_1_y = [1, 2, 3]. I can generate HTML plot for y vs x. trace = go.scatter(x=data_set_1_x, y=data_set_1_y). I have close to 25-30 data sets which overlay on top of one another.

Is there a way in Plotly to add a button which the user can click in the HTML where it can switch to plot y vs -x (for all data sets) or -y vs -x (for all data sets)? Or this can be done by only editing (switching sign of all y values and/or x values) raw data?

Comment: Wouldn't the data still be overlapping, just in the negative range?

Comment: I am not sure if I am communicating my question correctly. Different users in my group use different co-ordinate system in space (x,y). My (x,y) will be (x,-y) for some one or (-x,-y) for others. Was wondering if there is an easy way to transform all x data values from x to -x and/or y data values from y to -y. There is the option of dropdowns (https://plot.ly/python/dropdowns/). I can show or hide plots based on the dropdown choice. But, if there are a lot of data sets it becomes cumbersome.

Comment: In Bokeh you can edit frequency, amplitude of a sine wave for example using a callback function http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/slider.html . Was wondering if there is anything similar in Plotly. I want to transform f(x) to -f(x) and/or x to -x using buttons for 25-30 data sets together.